# Serving a GET request with nested callbacks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I have a generic Node+Express server where I serve GET requests. Some of these GET requests need multiple DB queries which are callbacks.
Here is an example of my code:

GET router:

```
router.get('/getbalance', function(req, res, next) {
    wallet.createNewAddress()
    .then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

This is the function with callbacks:

```
   async createNewAddress()
        {
            pool.query(`SELECT ...`)
            .then (dbres1 => {
                pool.query(`SELECT  ...`)
                .then(dbres2 => {
                        (async() => {
                            var pubkeys = await this.getPublicKeysFromIndexes(wallet.id, index_wallet_1, index_wallet_2, index_wallet_3);
                            var script = this.generateScript(pubkey1, pubkey2, pubkey3);
                        })();   
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e.stack);
                })
            }

        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.stack);
        });
    }
```

I have removed long statements for brevity.
As you can see, I have multiple levels of nested promises. 
What is the proper way to handle a request like this? Should I return each promise or should I run everything synchronously using `async()`?
What I need to do is to return the `script` at the very middle of the statements. This last call that returns the `script` is a normal synchronous function.
Appreciate any advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using async/await will give you much more readable code, while essentially following the same logic. Of course you will have to be aware that you'll need to add try/catch handler(s) to the code.

If you use async/await you'll end up with something like this:

```
async function createNewAddress()
{
    try {
        let dbres1 = await pool.query(`SELECT ...`);
        let dbres2 = await pool.query(`SELECT  ...`);

        var pubkeys = await this.getPublicKeysFromIndexes(wallet.id, index_wallet_1, index_wallet_2, index_wallet_3);    
        return this.generateScript(pubkey1, pubkey2, pubkey3);;
    } catch (err) {
        // ok something bad happened.. we could skip this handler and let the error bubble up to the top level handler if we're happy with that approach.
        console.error(err);
        // Rethrow or create new error here.. we don't want to swallow this.
        throw err;
    }
}
```

You can then call as before:

```
router.get('/getbalance', function(req, res, next) {
    wallet.createNewAddress()
    .then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Or use an async handler:

```
router.get('/getbalance', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let result = await wallet.createNewAddress();
        res.send(result);
    } catch (err) {
        // Also consider sending something back to the client, e.g. 500 error
        console.log(err);
    };
})
```

Comment: Thank you Terry. But this way wouldn't the GET call get blocked until all the db query `await`s are completed?

Comment: The GET call would finish straight away! It's async so it's non blocking. Counter intuitive, but really the async/await pattern is just syntactic sugar around Promises. The result would only be sent to the client once the db calls are finished though,  that's to be expected!